# Muliple search query in mongodb with springboot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I am creating a REST service using springboot and MONGO as database. I have a EmailIncomingFilter DTO and I am tryin g to use for multiple search like name or status or both

Comment: Clarify your question of what you are looking for? Isolation between transactions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JPA for this.
Create a repository and extend it to mongo repository. Create something like findByIdAndName method. And just call it from the service class pass the I'd and name as parameter.
Hopefully this should work.

Comment: My project in SpringBoot with db mongo